# PHP - build multilevel associative array from database (sorting cities by state from db)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I'm somewhat new to php and have been rattling my brain for the past few hours trying to figure this out. I need to sort cities by state from a database. I used the following query to retrieve the data set:

```
SELECT state, city FROM table ORDER BY state ASC, city ASC
```

This shows me the information I need when I run it as a query in phpMyAdmin, however I can't seem to figure out how to get it into an array and loop it.

The format I need to output is

```
CA
   Los Angeles
   San Francisco
New York
   Brooklyn
   Buffalo
```

I also need to be able to make each city return a link, but I'm pretty sure I can do that with ".item['$city']."

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Guys!

Ended up using the following code:

```
$query = ('SELECT DISTINCT state,city FROM table ORDER BY state ASC, city ASC');
$result = mysql_query($query);
$states = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if (!isset($exists[$row['state']])) {

        echo "<div id='location'><div class='state'><p>" . $row['state'] . "</p>";

        $exists[$row['state']] = true;
    }
    echo "<div class='city'><p><a href='?city=".$row['city']."' target='_blank'>".$row['city']."</a></p></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL will just give you a list out. You need to check if the current state is the same as the last state.  If it is, continue listing cities, otherwise, start a new segment, printing the state and city...

Java-like code:

```
lastState = "";
while(haveNext()) {
    if (currentRow.state!=lastState) println(currentRow.state);
    println(currentRow.city);
    lastState=currentRow.state;
}
```

Comment: I think he's looking for a PHP solution based on the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The results are already sorted, this should work:

```
$output = array();

foreach ($input as $value)
{
    if (array_key_exists($value['state'], $output) !== true)
    {
        $output[$value['state']] = array();
    }

    $output[$value['state']][] = $value['city'];
}

print_r($output);
```

**Input:**

```
$input = array
(
    0 => array
    (
        'state' => 'CA',
        'city' => 'Los Angeles',
    ),

    1 => array
    (
        'state' => 'CA',
        'city' => 'San Francisco',
    ),

    2 => array
    (
        'state' => 'New York',
        'city' => 'Brooklyn',
    ),

    3 => array
    (
        'state' => 'New York',
        'city' => 'Buffalo',
    ),
);
```

**Output ([@ CodePad](http://codepad.org/NZWV4DsI)):**

```
Array
(
    [CA] => Array
        (
            [0] => Los Angeles
            [1] => San Francisco
        )

    [New York] => Array
        (
            [0] => Brooklyn
            [1] => Buffalo
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like...

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT state,city FROM table ORDER BY state ASC, city ASC");

    $exists = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if (!isset($exists[$row['state']])) {

            echo '<p>' . $row['state'] . '</p>';

            $exists[$row['state']] = true;
        }

        echo '<p style="margin-left: 5px;">' . $row['city'] . '</p>';
    }   

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that code just sorts the cities, doesn't show states at all.

Comment: @Mike Odd.  Works fine for me.

Comment: You're right, I was the one that was actually wrong in how I phrased the initial question I suppose.  The results are listed, but seeing as how I have many entries per city, it lists each entry as a city versus only going STATE -> CITY.